# How to scale Two images together with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a small little project where i want to use the HTML/CSS checkbox-'hack' to simulate a toggleable image rotation. Problem is, when i add more content to the page and resize it, the images wont stay together at all.

I've tried scaling the images by % and vw/vh without success, as well as scaling the header above the images to make sure they don't 'jump' around when they move.

https://jsfiddle.net/9u3vz5mo/

```css
#cup {
  width: 75%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#mouth {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7%;
  height: 3%;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 43.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Paragraph Time, please let this work oh lord</h1>
<div class="images">
  <img id="cup" src="https://i.imgur.com/SFV05KS.png">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkmouth">
  <label for="checkmouth">                
        <img id="mouth" src="https://i.imgur.com/95acGMs.png">            
      </label>
</div>
```

What i hope to achieve is a version where the images scale responsivly to the sites size, and where the rest of the content is shown without having the mouth fly of the designated space on the cup.

Comment: can u plz show the more content.. how u add the more contents?

Comment: Sure thing! What i have as of now is just a simple <h1> above the div containing the image, as well as a paragraph below. Should look a little something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pjd4b50n/

Comment: sorry for that.. Can u plz explain clearly as what u want?

Comment: I would like that the cup's mouth to stay in the same position on the cup when re-sizing the window. Please check video here for example: https://imgur.com/a/UqzHosp

Comment: You can try to add a `position: relative` to the .images div to make the mouth position relatively to the images container, like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82uoL5gc/

Comment: Your image for the cup doesn't resize and keep it's aspect ratio, therefore you need to place the top value of the fly in relation to how your cups height resizes

Comment: Thanks guys! @Dax, you're solution worked wonders. Would you care to elaborate on the relative positioning? Still trying to learn what went wrong, and it would really help me out a lot!

Comment: @Kamil Ciekalski answer gave you a very quick explaination about positioning an absolute element. If you want a more in-depth guide I can suggest this good article with examples: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#article-header-id-1

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to parent element of both images (`.images` in this case) .
Then adjust position of `#mouth`

`position: absolute` elements are positioned relative to first parent element with `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

When setting the position to relative, you can add additional positioning attributes (top, bottom, left, right). The relative element is relative to itself. For example, if you set top: 10px the element will move 10px to the top from its normal position.

```css
.images{
  position: relative;
}

#cup {
    width: 75%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#mouth {
    position: absolute;
    width: 7%;
    height: 6%;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 58.5%;
    left: 50.5%;
}

#checkmouth {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + label > img {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

input:not(:checked) + label > img {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Paragraph Time, please let this work oh lord</h1>
    <div class="images">
      <img id="cup" src="https://i.imgur.com/SFV05KS.png">            
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkmouth">           
      <label for="checkmouth">                
        <img id="mouth" src="https://i.imgur.com/95acGMs.png">            
      </label>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always specify `100%` `width` or `vw` for scaling, and do not set a specified height for images you want to scale correctly. Place them in a `div` container.

Your problem is setting a specified `height` .